# replace default solve() by ginv

Tags: r

I want to replace `solve()` by `ginv()` in the mahanalobis function.

Is there any way to force any functions in R to use `ginv()` instead of `solve()`?

Answer (score 2):

The `mahalanobis` function is pretty simple.  Why not just define your own with the appropriate substitution, i.e.

```
mahalanobis_ginv <- function (x, center, cov, 
          inverted = FALSE, ...) {
    x <- if (is.vector(x)) 
        matrix(x, ncol = length(x))
    else as.matrix(x)
    if (!identical(center, FALSE)) 
        x <- sweep(x, 2L, center)
    if (!inverted) 
        cov <- MASS::ginv(cov, ...)
    setNames(rowSums(x %*% cov * x), rownames(x))
}
```

From `?mahalanobis`:

```
 ma <- cbind(1:6, 1:3)
 (S <-  var(ma))
 mahalanobis(c(0, 0), 1:2, S)  ## 5.37037
 mahalanobis_ginv(c(0, 0), 1:2, S) ## 5.37037
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that option. But, I'm trying to use covMcd and I have an singular matrix error produced by solve. And solve was called by mahalanobis. Because mahalanobis was called by covMcd. 

So, in this case I need to create mahalanobis_ginv. And also covMcd_something that should call mahalanobis_ginv.

I wonder if there is a simpler way.

Comment: what happens if you say `mahalanobis <- mahalanobis_ginv` (i.e. mask the version in the stats package with a version in your global workspace)?  You could even say `solve <- MASS::ginv`, but that seems a bit more dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You could type trace(mahalanobis, edit = T) and make the necessary replacements. When hitting save changes made to the function will only be stored for the current R session.

Answer (score 0):

why not try

```
cov <- solve(ginv(sigma))
```